# No clue where to start with Karma testing an angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am currently working on a school project, and everythign went fine untill the testing part.

I have to test my angularjs application with the Karma framework, but after installing everything I do not know where to start and how to test my application.

There should be 2 unit tests and 2 E2E test. Also, I have to use http backend for 1 test.

I followed this link for the structure of my application: 
http://thaiat.github.io/blog/2014/02/26/angularjs-and-requirejs-for-very-large-applications/

But now I do not know how to use it in combination with requirejs.

This is the code In have (tought it would be easier to let show it like this)
https://github.com/moepkid/angular-workshop

I followed a lot of tutorials but Everytime it doesnt completely show me how to incoorporate it into this structure I use. In this case I want to test my Store/controllers/StoreController.js file. I tried with easier code but couldnt make it work.

Can someone please give me a hint into the right direction?

Thanks!

(English is not my native language so sorry for any spelling mistakes)

Comment: this link may help you http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/02/27/karma-tutorial/ or try to find video tutorial where you can find more info than reading